# Triangle mesh (set of points 2D) with minmal total area: ' Convave Hull'

Tags: mesh

**modified question**

In the following example

```
pr = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}];
p = Select[pr , #[[1]] #[[2]] < .2 &];
Show[{ DelaunayMesh[p], ListPlot[p, PlotStyle -> Black], Plot[.2/x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

meshing (same with `ConvexHullMesh`) shows several elements above the hyperbolean which I would like to remove.

How to solve this problem for an arbitrary point set with Mathematica?

Thanks!

Comment: But one can still cut out some triangles from your last plot to reduce the area even more. And maybe make it = 0. What is the exact mathematical definition of the hull you are looking for? Notice that fig. 2 does not represents a convex hull.

Comment: You're right, the example is to simple. In my underlying problem I need to discretize a region (something like a triangle with a concave side) for further interpolation. Convexhull of this region expands the region unacceptable. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: @yarchik I'll modify my question...

Comment: Relevant keywords are "concave hull" and "α-concave hull".

Comment: @yarchik Appears to be promising, I'll test it.

Comment: @yarchik That's (`alphaShapes2D[ points,crit]`) what I'm looking for. Thanks! Now I have to optimize the code because for small values of  crit some points get lost...

Comment: Very nice that you found the right function! It is an interesting geometric problem.

Comment: @ yarchik Thanks for your helpful support. For my underlying problem I have to modify the alpha-shape function  in such a way, that it is only applied to boundary elements(triangle) of the region. Hope to find an easy solution...